# How to create multiple sockets using Socket.IO?

Tags: javascript, node.js, websocket, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

I don't know how to put forward this question to you. Actually I am creating an application which needs the following things:

- Many users will be registered on this app.
- Every user will be associated with one or more groups
- I want members of a particular group to broadcast messages to other group members using io.emit()

I have the following code:

```
var app=require('express')();
var http=require('http').Server(app);
var io=require('socket.io')(http);

app.get('/', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname +'/index.html');
});
io.use(function(socket,next){
    var handShakeData=socket.request;
    query1=handShakeData._query['groupId'];
    query2=handShakeData._query['message'];
    next();
});

io.on('connection',function(socket){
    console.log('A user connnected');
    io.emit('emittedMessages','A User Connected: '+query1+"  "+query2);
    socket.on('disconnect', function(){
         io.emit('emittedMessages','A User Disconnected');
         console.log('A user disconnected');
    });     
});


http.listen(3000,function(){
   console.log('Listening oon Port: 3000');
});
```

And this is my index.html file:

```
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io('http://localhost:3000',{query:"groupId=bar&message=bar2"});
  socket.connect();

  socket.on('emittedMessages',function(msg){
     $('body').append('<br/>'+msg);
  });
</script>
```

**Problem**

The problem with this code is that no matter what I do, It'll send message to every person in every group. How can I segregate different users of different groups to connect to different nodes/sockets so that I can broadcast messages into a particular group.

**I am sorry If I am not able to present the question properly. Please ask me if you have any doubts.** 
Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like you should use socket.io chat rooms.  They are built in groups of sockets and it's simple to broadcast to everyone in a given chat room and a given socket can be in 0, 1 or more chat rooms as desired.  You can read about rooms here: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/

Comment: Can you give me a example to clinet joining a chat room and server broadcasting.. Or any link?

Comment: What's wrong with the link in my previous comment?

Comment: I am not able to understand from that link.. How do you create a chat room at runtime? And how do you Broadcast to it?

Comment: It's right here: http://socket.io/docs/rooms-and-namespaces/#joining-and-leaving.  That's a very specific example of a server putting a client socket into a room and then broadcasting to the room.  Please spend some time reading the docs or asking specific questions about something in the doc you don't understand as it doesn't make sense to repeat general things that are written out there.